# cant install package with pip (ssl error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip, ssl-certificate

I was trying to install pywhatkit again. It stopped working for some reason. I also tried

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pywhatkit
```

but i only get this:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/pywhatkit/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/pywhatkit/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/pywhatkit/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/pywhatkit/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/pywhatkit/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pywhatkit/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pywhatkit/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),)) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywhatkit (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywhatkit
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)'),)) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple search on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/) shows that [`pywhatkit`](https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/) is available through a simple `pip install`:

```
$ pip install pywhatkit
Collecting pywhatkit
  Downloading pywhatkit-5.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting wikipedia
  Downloading wikipedia-1.4.0.tar.gz (27 kB)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting pyautogui
  Downloading PyAutoGUI-0.9.53.tar.gz (59 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 59 kB 1.3 MB/s 
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-8.4.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.1 MB 3.6 MB/s 
Collecting pymsgbox
  Downloading PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1
  Downloading pytweening-1.0.4.tar.gz (14 kB)
Collecting pyscreeze>=0.1.21
  Downloading PyScreeze-0.1.28.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting pygetwindow>=0.0.5
  Downloading PyGetWindow-0.0.9.tar.gz (9.7 kB)
Collecting mouseinfo
  Downloading MouseInfo-0.1.3.tar.gz (10 kB)
Collecting python3-Xlib
  Downloading python3-xlib-0.15.tar.gz (132 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 132 kB 6.7 MB/s 
Collecting pyrect
  Downloading PyRect-0.1.4.tar.gz (15 kB)
Collecting pyperclip
  Downloading pyperclip-1.8.2.tar.gz (20 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 97 kB 3.9 MB/s 
Collecting soupsieve>1.2
  Downloading soupsieve-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyautogui, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pygetwindow, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyTweening, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for mouseinfo, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyperclip, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyrect, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python3-Xlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for wikipedia, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: pyscreeze, pymsgbox
  Building wheel for pyscreeze (PEP 517) ... done
  Created wheel for pyscreeze: filename=PyScreeze-0.1.28-py3-none-any.whl size=13023 sha256=be44863ae17e02773581159a11ca3a39dbc3825f5b67f53f115866e48cf8b5dc
  Stored in directory: /home/username/.cache/pip/wheels/03/86/12/abd9680f6f63999ec0433afdbca9d26201eae26247bbbfb3a8
  Building wheel for pymsgbox (PEP 517) ... done
  Created wheel for pymsgbox: filename=PyMsgBox-1.0.9-py3-none-any.whl size=7420 sha256=90e67efa02c85831b532a212e8777fd1b82f70047ea45028e01eadfb4b905b99
  Stored in directory: /home/username/.cache/pip/wheels/b9/6a/ba/be2d7d78166ec8018c21d07241dffa54446c09652a267759ae
Successfully built pyscreeze pymsgbox
Installing collected packages: urllib3, soupsieve, python3-Xlib, pyrect, pyperclip, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, PyTweening, pyscreeze, pymsgbox, pygetwindow, mouseinfo, beautifulsoup4, wikipedia, pyautogui, Pillow, pywhatkit
    Running setup.py install for python3-Xlib ... done
    Running setup.py install for pyrect ... done
    Running setup.py install for pyperclip ... done
    Running setup.py install for PyTweening ... done
    Running setup.py install for pygetwindow ... done
    Running setup.py install for mouseinfo ... done
    Running setup.py install for wikipedia ... done
    Running setup.py install for pyautogui ... done
Successfully installed Pillow-8.4.0 PyTweening-1.0.4 beautifulsoup4-4.10.0 certifi-2021.10.8 charset-normalizer-2.0.8 idna-3.3 mouseinfo-0.1.3 pyautogui-0.9.53 pygetwindow-0.0.9 pymsgbox-1.0.9 pyperclip-1.8.2 pyrect-0.1.4 pyscreeze-0.1.28 python3-Xlib-0.15 pywhatkit-5.2 requests-2.26.0 soupsieve-2.3.1 urllib3-1.26.7 wikipedia-1.4.0
```

Which OS and which version of `pip` are you using when trying to install `pywhatkit` ?

Comment: Im using Windows 11 and pip version 21.3.1. And from one of the other day i cant install ANY packages because of an ssl error.